# How can I regexp capture the string between 2 specific sets of double underscores?

Tags: regex, perl

I want to regexp capture the string between 2 specific sets of double underscores.  The string that get captured may itself have single underscore occurrences in it.  Here's the test Perl script I've been working with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;

my $str = "DFD_20220913_121409_strix1a0__z1_erx_adm__CL1695331__RTL_Dfdsg4__regression__df_umc_nbio_hubs_gfx__220913_150718";
(my $grp) = $str =~ /CL\d+\_\_(\w+)\_\_/;
print "grp = $grp\n";

exit;
```

This returns...

```
grp = RTL_Dfdsg4__regression__df_umc_nbio_hubs_gfx
```

I want...

```
grp = RTL_Dfdsg4
```

As you can see, I know something about where the first set of double underscores exists (after the `CL\d+`).  But for some reason, the regexp reads past the next occurrence of the double underscores until it hits the last set.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the non-greedy quantifier, `?`.

```
(my $grp) = $str =~ /CL\d+__(\w+?)__/;
```

I removed the unnecessary backslashes from before the underscores.

Answer (score 3):

Note that using the non-greedy modifier is fragile and can easily work differently than intended. This is the robust alternative:

```perl
my ( $grp ) = $str =~ /
   CL \d+
   __ 
   ( [^\W_]+ (?: _ [^\W_]+ )* )     # `[^\W_]` is `\w` minus `_`
   __
/x;
```